# Checking existence of a record in a SQL table using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

The query below returns 'Found'  when the records with ID exists in services table but does not return 'Not Found'  when the record does not exists in the services table. I can't figure out why.

```
select case when  exists (select idaccount from services  where idaccount 
=s.idaccount )
 then 'Found'
 else 'NotFound'  end as GSO  
 from services s 
 where s.idaccount in ( 1421)
```

Comment: What is it returning when the record does not exist?  No rows, right?

Comment: Yes No rows returned

Comment: is `idaccountt` a typo or are you intentionally referring to another field?

Comment: Yes , it was a typo , corrected it

Comment: Ignore your case expression. You are selecting rows. If no matching row exists, an empty resultset is generated; there is nothing to be evaluated by your case expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query will only ever return a row if it exists, so the case statement is redundant, you could just as well write

```
SELECT 'Found' FROM services s WHERE s.idaccount IN (1421)
```

Although it makes very little sense, you could write something like:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM services WHERE idaccount = 1421)
         THEN 'Found'

         ELSE 'NotFound'
       END
```

Note lack of `FROM` clause in the outermost `SELECT`. Quicker way to write the same thing:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT 'Found' FROM services WHERE idaccount = 1421), 'NotFound')
```

Comment: Thank You, Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner `CASE WHEN EXISTS` **only gets evaluated** if the outer query finds data, which is why you never see 'NotFound'.

The version below is not only shorter, also it will work because the `CASE WHEN EXISTS` is always evaluated:

```
select case when exists (
        select 1 from services where idaccount = 1421
    )
    then 'Found'
    else 'NotFound' end as GSO
```